# Laravel Validator fails everytime even i has posted data

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

*I am new to laravel and trying to use Validator class. It fails everytime though form post the data. i have googled and digged a lot to get answer from internet but none of them worked for me. Please stack guys help me out to get rid of this issue.*

**This is my Conntroller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;

class AuthenticationController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function login()
    {
        return view('login');
    }
    public function register()
    {
        return view('register');
    }
    public function addUser(Request $request)
    {
        $Validator=Validator::make($request->all(),array('fname'=>'required'));
        if($Validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($Validator->messages());
        }
    }
    
}
```

**This is register blade view file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
  <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="wrapper fadeInDown">
  <div id="formContent">
    <!-- Tabs Titles -->
                   
  <!-- Login Form -->
    <form method="POST" action="{{url('/register.submit')}}">
      <input type="text" id="first-name" class="fadeIn second" name="
      fname" placeholder="First Name">
      @if($errors->has('fname'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
      {{$errors->first('fname')}}
      </div>
      @endif
      @csrf
      
      <input type="text" id="last-name" class="fadeIn second" name="
      lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
      @if($errors->has('last_name'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
      {{$errors->first('last_name')}}
      </div>
      @endif

      <input type="text" id="email" class="fadeIn second" name="
      email" placeholder="Email">
      @if($errors->has('email'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
      {{$errors->first('email')}}
      </div>
      @endif
      
      <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="password">
      @if($errors->has('password'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
      {{$errors->first('password')}}
      </div>
      @endif

      <input type="password" id="confirm-password" class="fadeIn third" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password">
      @if($errors->has('confirm_password'))
      <div class="alert-danger">
      {{$errors->first('confirm_password')}}
      </div>
      @endif

      <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Register">
    </form>

    <!-- Remind Passowrd -->
    <div id="formFooter">
      <a class="underlineHover" href="{{url('login')}}">Already have account SignIn</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a class="underlineHover" href="{{url('forget_password')}}">Forget Password</a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if we code like if($validator->fails()){ return $request->all()} it shows all posted data filled up whatever filledup at the time of form submit.

Comment: Does it even hit your `addUser` method? You have an _URL_ `/register.submit`, sure that isn't a route name? Is it mapped to your `addUser` method? Can we see you routes?

Comment: this is the route i have defined Route::post('/register.submit','AuthenticationController@addUser')->name('register.submit');

Comment: Is `name="
      fname"` actually on two lines?

Comment: @brombeer you hit the right thing, actually it was auto wrap from sublime while i warp manually like name='fname' in new line and tested its working fine!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `name` attributes are actually in *one* line and don't spread over two lines. Showing those in code tags here will result in:
`name=" fname"`

When you display such string in HTML you'll most likely see the whitespace stripped, but PHP/Laravel recognizes it as whitespace and thus your validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually into view file editor sublime has wrap code like**

```
<input type="text" id="first-name" class="fadeIn second" name="
      fname" placeholder="First Name">
```

**so (i hope so) laravel consider it like name='   fname' when i edited code like**

```
<input type="text" id="first-name" class="fadeIn second" 
    name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
```

**After this change it works fine.**